Using PlaceId's with Advanced Markers
Using legacy markers you could add markers using placeId's like
var service = new google.maps.places.PlacesService(map);
service.getDetails({
    placeId: 'ChIJN1t_tDeuEmsRUsoyG83frY4'
}, function (result, status) {
    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        map: map,
        place: {
            placeId: 'ChIJN1t_tDeuEmsRUsoyG83frY4',
            location: result.geometry.location
        }
    });
})

Is it possible to do the same with AdvancedMarkers? Trying to do the same above google.maps.marker.AdvancedMarkerElement({...}) throws a invalidValueError.

That place property is not even documented in the API reference. I found one Place details example that uses it but that's the first time I see that. As you found out by now, the result in the callback has everything you need.

The result from service.getDetails contains a lat lng object in result.geometry.location. You can place the marker with something like this:
var service = new google.maps.places.PlacesService(map);
service.getDetails({
    placeId: 'ChIJN1t_tDeuEmsRUsoyG83frY4'
}, function (result, status) {
    var marker = new google.maps.marker.AdvancedMarkerElement({
        map: map,
        position: result.geometry.location,
        title: result.name
    });
})

